# Compare date time to another table date_time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

```
select uid , max(price) keep(dense_rank last order by usage_date ASC) amount 
from HISTORY group by uid" ;
```

compare HISTORY to ADJUSTMENT
If the latest usage_date (each id ) is before (sen_date)
I would like to add the price of ADJUSTMENT
How can I do this ?

*I want to add the price of ADJUSTMENT to max(price) if usage_date is older than ADJUSTMENT
in this case uid= 5 is should be added 200

```
ADJUSTMENT
uid,price,sen_date
1,100,2020-10-23
2,200,2020-10-23
2,200,2020-09-22
2,200,2020-08-23
2,200,2020-10-22
3,300,2020-10-20
5,200,2020-10-20


HISTORY
uid,price,usage_date
1,1000,2020-10-23
1,1000,2020-10-19
1,1000,2020-10-03
2,1000,2020-10-23
3,1000,2020-10-23
3,1000,2020-10-23
3,1000,2020-10-23
4,1000,2020-10-20
4,1000,2020-10-23
4,1000,2020-10-19
4,1000,2020-10-23
4,1000,2020-10-23
5,1000,2020-10-02
5,1000,2020-10-03
5,1000,2020-10-04
6,1000,2020-10-23
7,1000,2020-10-23
```

Comment: You want to update the history table and change the row `5,1000,2020-10-04` to `5,1200,2020-10-04`?

Comment: Sorry It seems to be easy to misunderstand.
select uid , max(price) keep(dense_rank last order by usage_date ASC) amount 
from HISTORY group by uid" ; I would like to only fetch data with adding  [amount ] to price(from adjustment)

Comment: Okay, no update, but a query. Can you please just update your request and show the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Take your query and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it to a similar query for the `ADJUSTMENT` table correlating on `uid` with a later date and then use `COALESCE` to combine the dates:

```
SELECT h."UID",
       h.usage_date,
       a.sen_date,
       h.price AS base_price,
       COALESCE( a.price, 0 ) AS price_adjustment,
       h.price + COALESCE( a.price, 0 ) AS price
FROM   (
         SELECT "UID",
                MAX( usage_date ) AS usage_date,
                MAX(price) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY usage_date ASC) AS price
         FROM   HISTORY
         GROUP BY "UID"
       ) h
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT "UID",
                MAX( sen_date ) AS sen_date,
                MAX(price) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sen_date ASC) AS price
         FROM   ADJUSTMENT
         GROUP BY "UID"
       ) a
       ON ( h."UID" = a."UID" AND h.usage_date < a.sen_date )
ORDER BY "UID"
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE adjustment ( "UID",price,sen_date ) AS
SELECT 1,100,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,200,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,200,DATE '2020-09-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,200,DATE '2020-08-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,200,DATE '2020-10-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,300,DATE '2020-10-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,200,DATE '2020-10-20' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE HISTORY ( "UID",price,usage_date) AS
SELECT 1,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1000,DATE '2020-10-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1000,DATE '2020-10-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1000,DATE '2020-10-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1000,DATE '2020-10-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1000,DATE '2020-10-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1000,DATE '2020-10-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1000,DATE '2020-10-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,1000,DATE '2020-10-23' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> UID | USAGE_DATE | SEN_DATE  | BASE_PRICE | PRICE_ADJUSTMENT | PRICE
> --: | :--------- | :-------- | ---------: | ---------------: | ----:
>   1 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
>   2 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
>   3 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
>   4 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
>   5 | 04-OCT-20  | 20-OCT-20 |       1000 |              200 |  1200
>   6 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
>   7 | 23-OCT-20  | null      |       1000 |                0 |  1000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f6558c21d4c15c16eafa38d0f32f7f75)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have a question.
If ADJUSTMENT has  some records that are fetched .
Like this 
5,200,2020-10-20
5,200,2020-10-17
I would like to add both.

What  should I do In this case?

(
                MAX( sen_date ) AS sen_date,
                SUM(price) AS price
)a

Instead of 
(
                MAX( sen_date ) AS sen_date,
                MAX(price) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sen_date ASC) )
)a?

Comment: @conny If you only want the sum for only a number of equally-latest values then `SUM(price) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sen_date ASC)`. If you want the sum for all the values (not just the latest) then just use `SUM(price)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean this (shown [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c82673189502372fad2b2dfe0232ad41))?

```
SELECT a.* FROM adjustment a 
WHERE  a.sen_date > (SELECT max(usage_date) FROM history WHERE uid = a.uid)
```